# NestedScrollView with RecyclerView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

`NestedScrollView` with `RecyclerView` in it is not scrolling

I have tried all the options discussed in this forum .. looks like I am still missing something.. Please see my code my below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="message"
            type="Post" />
    </data>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    style="@style/MyCardViewStyle"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/post_card1"

                    >


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/image_gallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/doc_gallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/post_replies"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</layout>
```

And I have set `isNestedScrollingEnabled = false` on all three `RecyclerViews`.

Screen just seems to be stuck and not at all scrolling

Comment: Maybe because all `layout_height` parameters inside `NestedScrollView` are set to `wrap_content`? What do you get as result?

Comment: In one case I have data in first and third recyclerviews. I can see data in 3rd one going beyond view, but I still cant scroll down. If I change layout_height parameter to match_parent, none of recyclerviews are visible

Comment: Try setting the height of your `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`.

Comment: Tried, did not help

Answer (score -1):

Create separate layout files for recycler views. And include those into the list view.

You have something like

```
<LinuearLayout ..>
  <CardView>
  <RecyclerView>
  <RecyclerView>
  <RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can change it to,

```
<LinuearLayout ..>
  <include layout="@layout/cv1"/>
  <include layout="@layout/rv1"/>
  <include layout="@layout/rv2"/>
  <include layout="@layout/rv3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is just a clue to you. I did solve similar issues long back in past. Please try experimenting with this clue.